# Write the shortest game of alak

Tags: code-golf, board-game

> Alak was invented by the mathematician A. K.  Dewdney, and described in his 1984 book Planiverse. The rules of Alak are simple:
>
> Alak is a two-player game played on a one-dimensional board with eleven slots on it.  Each slot can hold at most one piece at a
>   time.  There's two kinds of pieces, "x" and "o". x's belong to one player, o's to the other.
>   The initial configuration of the board is:

```
      xxxx___oooo
```

> The players take turns moving.  At each turn, each player can move only one piece, once.  A player cannot pass up on his turn.  A player
>   can move any one of his pieces to the next unoccupied slot to its right or left, which may involve jumping over occupied slots.  A
>   player cannot move a piece off the side of the board.
>
> If a move creates a pattern where the opponent's pieces are surrounded, on both sides, by two pieces of the mover's color (with no
>   intervening unoccupied blank slot), then those surrounded pieces are removed from the board.
>
> The goal of the game is to remove all of your opponent's pieces, at which point the game ends.  Removing all-but-one ends the game
>   as well, since the opponent can't surround you with one piece, and so will always lose within a few moves anyway.

I found this game online and was wondering: can it be golfed?

#### Rules of the golf

- Your code must follow all the rules in the game, handling captures, proper moving, etc. (only exception is you don't have to add a bot, but you must have both players controlled somehow, and one player must be human).
- Input must be move piece at tile X to tile Y, or quit. For example, you can use `1 4` to say 'move this piece at tile 1 to tile 4'. `quit` would end the program, although using <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> would be acceptable. You also have to check if a move is invalid (by going outside the board or moving somewhere that you would have to cross over unoccupied spaces to get to or sending a message that is not a pair of tiles or `quit`).
- Outputs for players winning and invalid must be `P1 WINS`, `P2 WINS`, and `INVALID`, respectively. (All of these are 7 characters.)
- Output must show the board. That's all that's required.
- It doesn't matter if you use any aids like numbered tiles or other pieces.
- The challenge ends if:

  - One answer gets 50 votes
  - One answer remains the top-voted for 3 weeks, and no other answers were posted in that time

and the challenge has at least 3 answers (so there's some real competition).

#### Rules of the game

- The player on the left must start first.
- Only one piece occupies a square at a time. You move the piece left or right until it hits an unoccupied space. The board does not wrap, and you can't move through unoccupied areas. For example:

  - `xoo__o`. Here, the `x` moving right would change the board to `_oox_o`.
  - `xxooo_`. Here, the farthest-left `x` could move to yield `_xooox`, which captures the `o`s, leaving `_x___x`.
  - `x__oox`. Here, the `o`s are not captured (there is still a gap). Capture is not possible because you can't move through unoccupied spaces. The `x` on the left could only move one space, because there are no other pieces in between (leaving `_x_oox`).
- Multiple adjacent pieces can be captured at once if the group is surrounded by the opponent's pieces. E.g. from `x_oox` to `_xoox` will capture both `o`s and result in `_x__x`.
- If after a move, you first capture the *opponent's* pieces, before checking if your own piece should be remove. Take two examples:

  - `o_oxx` to `oxox_`. First, the second `o` is captured, `ox_x_`, so the first `x` remains on the board.
  - `o_oox` to `oxoo_`. This time, none of the `o`s are captured, so the `x` is captured instead.
  - If you have only one piece, the game ends, because you can't capture with just one piece.

Let the games begin! I look forward to seeing what you come up with.

Comment: Comments purged, as they were obsolete. Please notify me of any comments that should be undeleted.

Answer (score 9):

## C, <s>617</s> 592 bytes

```c
#define O(x)(x-'x'?'x':'o')
q,f,t,k,i,x=4,o=4,*d;main(){char*A,Q[9],c='x',b[]="xxxx___oooo";printf(b);while(!q){scanf(" %8[^\n]%*[^\n]",Q);if(!strcmp(Q,"quit"))break;f=*Q>47&&*Q<58?atoi(Q):-1;A=f>9?Q+2:Q+1;t=*A==32&&A[1]>47&&A[1]<58?atoi(A+1):-1;i=t==f&&t<0&&f<0?1:0;for(k=f;k!=t;k+=(t-f)/abs(t-f))if(b[k]==95||b[t]-95||b[f]-c)i=1;if(i){printf("INVALID");continue;}b[t]=c;b[f]=95;for(t=0;t<2;t++){d=c-'x'?&o:&x;for(k=1;k<11;k++)if(b[k]==O(c)){for(i=k+1;b[i]==O(c)&&b[i];i++);if(b[i]==c&&b[k-1]==c)while(k<i)b[k++]=95,(*d)--;}c=t?c:O(c);}printf(b);if(o<2||x<2)printf("P%d WINS",(x>1)+1),q=1;}}
```

Unraveled:

```c
#define O(x)(x-'x'?'x':'o')
q,f,t,k,i,x=4,o=4,*d;
main(){
    char*A,Q[9],c='x',b[]="xxxx___oooo";
    printf(b);
    while(!q){
        scanf(" %8[^\n]%*[^\n]",Q);
        if(!strcmp(Q,"quit"))break;
        f=*Q>47&&*Q<58?atoi(Q):-1;
        A=f>9?Q+2:Q+1;
        t=*A==32&&A[1]>47&&A[1]<58?atoi(A+1):-1;
        i=t==f&&t<0&&f<0?1:0;
        for(k=f;k!=t;k+=(t-f)/abs(t-f))
            if(b[k]==95||b[t]-95||b[f]-c)
                i=1;
        if(i){
            printf("INVALID");
            continue;
        }
        b[t]=c;
        b[f]=95;
        for(t=0;t<2;t++){
            d=c-'x'?&o:&x;
            for(k=1;k<11;k++)
                if(b[k]==O(c)){
                    for(i=k+1;b[i]==O(c)&&b[i];i++);
                    if(b[i]==c&&b[k-1]==c)
                        while(k<i)b[k++]=95,(*d)--;
                }
            c=t?c:O(c);
        }
        printf(b);
        if(o<2||x<2)printf("P%d WINS",(x>1)+1),q=1;
    }
}
```

I really wanted to get this one in ~400 bytes, but there are a lot of little rules here and the input processing ended up pretty obnoxious. I'm definitely not done with this. Here's a set of sample runs that covers just about everything:

```
xxxx___oooo0 4
_xxxx__oooo7 6
_xxxx_o_ooo4 5
_xxx_xo_ooo8 6
INVALID8 7
_xxx_xoo_oo3 4
_xx_xxoo_oo7 3
_xxo__o__oo1 4
__x_x_o__oo10 9
INVALID10 8
__x_x_o_oo_2 3
___xx_o_oo_6 5
___xxo__oo_6 6
INVALID5 5
INVALID3 6
____x_x_oo_8 7
____x_xo_o_6 8
____x__o_o_P2 WINS
 
xxxx___oooo0 4
_xxxx__oooo10 6
_xxxx_oooo_1 5
__xxxxoooo_9 1
_o____ooo__P2 WINS
 
xxxx___oooo0 4
_xxxx__oooo7 6
_xxxx_o_ooo1 5
__xxxxo_ooo10 7
__xxxxoooo_2 10
___xxx____xP1 WINS
 
xxxx___oooo3 4
xxx_x__ooooquits
INVALIDtestme
INVALID3*4
INVALID3 four
INVALIDthree four
INVALIDthisstringislongerthanmybuffer
INVALID10 0
INVALID4 5
INVALID7 6
xxx_x_o_oooquit
```

If I've misinterpreted something, please let me know!

Comment: I tested it, it works well, and nothing was left out. Good job!

Comment: You can save a few bytes by replacing `printf("INVALID");` with `puts("INVALID");`, `o<2||x<2` with `o<2|x<2` and `printf(b);while(!q){` with `for(printf(b);!q;){`

Comment: [494 bytes](https://tio.run/##NVHRitswEHzPV/hcokiyBFaatGfLG2O4l0C51BTaB9cNsRxdhVv7nOjAkKS/nsouXRC7O5qdWSHFX5S639/VR23ao7fzxDLkEcUKYDEsyKxnljXMsAFWrHOH1vL3wbRYk4v6eTjRjOVFVLKqKMEfXOz3@86FzxTQSuruhF/f7BlXRD70CJ3VodXY9@aPxY/vbTmnU/JZThBaWPPWLzjFprWU5LKHLlleh2SZvp4c5MY@z2vv2/b5i8/wsBEkECTuyaUBDTTfrD4imifrx/RgO4NzEnMhLTyYc21ejMWiyCDnf7DeRKQkV5rx98uUi3hiZ05q2tWABdDIJqFsuJVNAHajU@G0iLlCVTQlQLS@VoUt@ZR1yZU0GhsyPdPfPn/NPm2ffCKPv87Hy0gEJUeem5ssLCyl5VwqsKmKd2TEGghZDTskUjTEqJNB0CRCSOKEq8LA6Lojl5HppILAjL0k8t@1axRyq3ExVpOebBIjOac1cXgQTN63//9wu93u99BbzUTofZgJbz2LPPEX "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 3):

## PHP - 505

```
<?php
$s="xxxx___ooo".$y=o;$x=x;$c=function($m)use(&$x){return$x.str_repeat('_',strlen($m[1])).$x;};$e='$s=preg_replace_callback("~$x($y+)$x~",$c,$s);';$_=substr_count;while(true){echo$s;if($_($s,x)<2)die("P2 WINS");if($_($s,o)<2)die("P1 WINS");$i=trim(fgets(STDIN));if($i=='quit')die;if(!preg_match('!^(\d+) (\d+)$!',$i,$m)||$s[$f=$m[1]]!=$x||$s[$t=$m[2]]!="_"||(0&($a=min($f,$t))&$b=max($f,$t))||$_($s,"_",$a,($b-$a)+1)>1)echo"INVALID\n";else{$s[$f]='_';$s[$t]=$x;eval($e);$z=$x;$x=$y;$y=$z;eval($e);}}
```

Notices must be suppressed by redirecting `STDERR` to `/dev/null`.

With sane whitespace:

```
<?php
@$s = "xxxx___ooo".($y = o);
@$x = x;
$c = function($m)usea(&$x){
    return$x.str_repeat('_',strlen($m[1])).$x;
};
$e = '$s=preg_replace_callback("~$x($y+)$x~",$c,$s);';
@$_ = substr_count;
while (true){
    echo $s;

    if (@$_($s,x) < 2) die("P2 WINS");
    if (@$_($s,o) < 2) die("P1 WINS");

    $i = trim(fgets(STDIN));
    if($i == 'quit') die;

    if( !preg_match('!^(\d+) (\d+)$!',$i,$m)
    ||   $s[$f = $m[1]] != $x
    ||  @$s[$t = $m[2]] != "_"
    ||  (0 & ($a = min($f, $t)) & $b = max($f, $t))
    ||  $_($s, "_", $a, ($b - $a) + 1) > 1
    ) echo "INVALID\n";
    else {
        $s[$f] = '_';
        $s[$t] = $x;
        eval($e);
        $z = $x;
        $x = $y;
        $y = $z;
        eval($e);
    }
}
```

With the test cases of BrainSteel:

```
xxxx___oooo0 4
_xxxx__oooo7 6
_xxxx_o_ooo4 5
_xxx_xo_ooo8 6
INVALID
_xxx_xo_ooo8 7
_xxx_xoo_oo3 4
_xx_xxoo_oo7 3
_xxo__o__oo1 4
__x_x_o__oo10 9
INVALID
__x_x_o__oo10 8
__x_x_o_oo_2 3
___xx_o_oo_6 5
___xxo__oo_6 6
INVALID
___xxo__oo_5 5
INVALID
___xxo__oo_3 6
____x_x_oo_8 7
____x_xo_o_6 8
____x__o_o_P2 WINS

xxxx___oooo0 4
_xxxx__oooo10 6
_xxxx_oooo_1 5
__xxxxoooo_9 1
_o____ooo__P2 WINS

xxxx___oooo0 4
_xxxx__oooo7 6
_xxxx_o_ooo1 5
__xxxxo_ooo10 7
__xxxxoooo_2 10
___xxx____xP1 WINS

xxxx___oooo3 4
xxx_x__ooooquits
INVALID
xxx_x__ooootestme
INVALID
xxx_x__oooo3*4
INVALID
xxx_x__oooo3 four
INVALID
xxx_x__oooothree four
INVALID
xxx_x__oooothisstringislongerthanmybuffer
INVALID
xxx_x__oooo10 0
INVALID
xxx_x__oooo4 5
INVALID
xxx_x__oooo7 6
xxx_x_o_oooquit
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'notices/warnings'?

Comment: @ASCIIThenANSI Warnings because of unquoted character literals: PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant o - assumed 'o' in /tmp/pcg-48388.php on line 2. One can redirect them to /dev/null.

Comment: Does that break the program?

Comment: @ASCIIThenANSI No, it does work fine is they are redirected to `/dev/null`.

Comment: Then it's OK to have it as long as the program continues to function properly, and they are redirected to `/dev/null`.

Comment: @ASCIIThenANSI I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, <s>536</s> <s>509</s> <s>448</s> 441 bytes

Call via `a()`; moves are to be entered in the form `piece,destination` (i.e., `1,4`); quit with Ctrl-C. If anyone can see more golfing potential, I'm all ears.

```
b,r,x='_',lambda p:''.join([p[i]for i in x]),range(11)
def a(m='xo'):
 t=w=0;p=dict(zip(x,'xxxx___oooo'))
 while w<1:
    print r(p);y=m[t%2]
    try:
     s,v=input();1/all([y==p[s],{v}<{r(p).rfind(b,0,s),r(p).find(b,s)},v-s]);p[s],p[v],h,c=b,y,0,{}  
     for _ in y,m[-~t%2]:
        for i in p:exec{_:"h=1;p.update(c)",b:"h,c=0,{}"}.get(p[i],h*"c[i]=b")
     w=min(map(r(p).count,m))<2;t+=1
    except:print"INVALID"
 print"P%d WINS"%-~(r(p).count('o')<2)
```

Answer (score 1):

## SpecBAS - 718 bytes

[SpecBAS](https://sites.google.com/site/pauldunn/) is an updated version of Sinclair/ZX BASIC that can run outside of an emulator. (Still interpreted).

Have used some of the new features to get the size down as much as I could.

Line 12 sets up a regex to search for "sandwiched" pieces using inline IF and line 18 uses the wrap around nature of INC (rather than saying `INC p: IF p=3 THEN LET p=1`)

```
1 LET b$="xxxx---oooo": LET p=1: LET c$="xo": DIM s=4,4
2 LET v=0: PRINT b$'"[";p;"] ";
3 INPUT m$: IF m$(1)="Q" THEN PRINT "QUIT": STOP 
4 LET f=VAL(ITEM$(m$,1," ")): LET t=VAL(ITEM$(m$,2," ")): PRINT f;" ";t
5 IF (f<1 OR f>11) OR (t<1 OR t>11) THEN LET v=1: GO TO 10
6 IF (b$(f)<>c$(p)) OR b$(t)<>"-" THEN LET v=1: GO TO 10
7 FOR i=f TO t STEP SGN(t-f)
8 IF b$(i)="-" THEN IF i<>t THEN LET v=1
9 NEXT i
10 IF v=1 THEN PRINT "INVALID": GO TO 2
11 LET b$(t)=b$(f): LET b$(f)="-"
12 LET r$=IIF$(p=1,"xo+x","ox+o")
13 LET m=MATCH(r$,b$): IF m=0 THEN GO TO 18
14 FOR i=m+1 TO POS(c$(p),b$,m+2)
15 IF b$(i)=c$(3-p) THEN LET b$(i)="-": DEC s(3-p): END IF
16 NEXT i
17 IF s(3-p)<2 THEN PRINT b$'"P";p;" WINS": STOP 
18 INC p,1 TO 2
19 GO TO 2
```

Output (can't copy from the output widow, so screen shot)
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

## C#, 730 bytes

```
using System;using System.Linq;class P{static void Main(string[]z){int p=1,d,e,g,x,y;var b=new[]{3,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,2,2,2,2};var o=new[]{"_","x","o"};Action<string>h=s=>{Console.Write(s,p);Environment.Exit(0);};Action i=()=>h("INVALID");Func<int,int,bool>j=(q,r)=>b.Select((v,w)=>w<=q||w>=r||v>0?0:w).Any(w=>w>0);Action<int>k=m=>{e=0;for(d=1;d<12;d++){if(b[d]==m){if(e>0&&!j(e,d))for(g=e+1;g<d;g++)b[g]=0;e=d;}}if(b.Count(w=>w>0&&w!=m)<3)h("P{0} WINS");};try{for(;;){for(g=1;g<12;g++)Console.Write(o[b[g]]);var n=Console.ReadLine();if(n=="quit")h("");var c=n.Split(' ');x=int.Parse(c[0]);y=int.Parse(c[1]);if(c.Length>2||b[x]!=p||b[y]!=0||(p>1?y:x)>=(p>1?x:y)||j(x<y?x:y,x<y?y:x))i();b[x]=0;b[y]=p;k(p);p=p>1?1:2;k(p);}}catch{i();}}}
```

I imagine that further improvements are possible.  On the other hand, I interpreted the `INVALID` output as ending execution, so I may need to fix that issue to be in parity with other answers.